# why does it say that it needs to be modifiable and it needs to be a constant

Tags: c

when I wrote this code in c

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void) {
        const int k = 7;
        int a[k];
        k = 9;
        return 0;
    }
```

there was an error saying that the k in the brackets needs to be a constant value(expression must have a constant value) and the other k needs to be a modifiable value(expression must be a modifiable lvalue). This doesn't make any sense. Am I doing something wrong? I thought that you can put constant variables as the size of an array.

Comment: Please give the exact and complete error messages.

Comment: Hey!, why `k=9;` ??

Comment: `int a[k];` is a VLA (Variable Length Array). Not all compilers support that. So please also tell us the compiler you are using.

Comment: You may be confusing this with C++, where `const int` is a constant value. This is not the case in C though (for the purpose of array size declarations)

Comment: I use Microsoft Visual C++

Comment: MSVC does not support VLA. Change that to be `int a[7];` or use `#define MY_SIZE 7` or use dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: thank you and sorry. I don't know why but I was sure that I could use constants.

Comment: @HangyeolYoo You can use constants in C.  But `const int k` is not a constant.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I doing something wrong? I thought that you can put constant variables as the size of an array.

Yes, in C99 and later when [*variable length arrays*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array#C99) (VLA) are supported.

Earlier versions of MSVC do not support VLA nor C99.
As of 2020 [Astute readers will note that VLAs are also not supported](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c11-and-c17-standard-support-arriving-in-msvc/) in MSVC C11.

---

> why does it say that it needs to be modifiable and it needs to be a constant

These are 2 different problems in 2 lines of code.

When *variable length arrays* (VLA) are not supported, an array declaration width must be a *constant*.  `const int k` is not a *constant*.

```
const int k = 7;
int a[k];  // k is not a constant.

// Alternate
#define K 7
int a[K];  // K is a constant.
```

---

Modifying a `const`  object is prohibited.

```
    const int k = 7;
    ...
    k = 9;
```

Instead,

```
    int k = 7;
    ...
    k = 9;
```

Comment: "`const int k` is not a constant" is weird enough a sentence to warrant an explanation. Stroustrup seemed to find it weird, too, and changed it for C++, where the array would not be a variable length array (which don't exist there, of course).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Baby steps - we are taking OP from the contradictory phrase "constant variables" (are they constants or are they variables?) to `const` and _constant_.  Bringing in another language loses focus on this C question.

Comment: By the way, nitpick: "Variable *Length* Array" ...  support*ed* ;-).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Logic to length amended.

Answer (score 1):

`const`-qualifying a variable does not make it a compile time constant, so `int a[k]` declares a variable length array. Variable lenghth arrays are only supported in C99 and later and not all compilers support them.

Also, with `k = 9`, you are trying to modify a `const`-qualified variable, which is not allowed.

Solution would be to either use C99 or later and a compiler that supports variable length arrays or (in this case probably better) to define the array size as a preprocessor constant (e.g. `#define k 10`) .